# In Symfony EasyAdmin PAGE_INDEX can we pass value of one field to another

Tags: easyadmin, symfony6

I'm trying to pass alternative text to image field.

```php
if (Crud::PAGE_INDEX === $pageName) {
            return [$id, $image->setTemplatePath('easy_admin/block/_images_list.html.twig')->setCustomOptions(['alt' => (String) $title, 'width' => 50, 'action' => 'detail']),
                $entityVal, $mimeType, $size];
        }
```

*Hint:-* Here `$title` is another field such as `$id`,`$mimeType` etc.

**ERROR**

```bash
Object of class EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\TextField could not be converted to string
```

**Question:-**
Can we pass value of one field to another in EASYADMIN PAGE_INDEX or do we have to hack the twig?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I done this in twig.
I have two entity Page and User.
From PageEntity:-

```php
    #[ORM\ManyToOne]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?User $author = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, unique: true)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank()]
    #[Assert\Length(min: 3, max: 255)]
    private ?string $title = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[Gedmo\Slug(fields: ["title"], updatable: false, separator: "-")]
    private ?string $slug = null;
```

From UserEntity:-

```php
    #[ORM\Column(length: 180, unique: true)]
    private ?string $email = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 45, unique: true)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank()]
    #[Assert\Length(min: 3, max: 45)]
    private ?string $username = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 64, unique: true)]
    #[Gedmo\Slug(fields: ['username'])]
    private ?string $slug = null;
```

AdminCrud PAGE:-

```php
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable {
  $author = AssociationField::new('author');
  $slug = TextField::new('slug')->setRequired(false);
  $title = TextField::new('title');
  if (Crud::PAGE_INDEX === $pageName) {
    return [$title->setTemplatePath('easy_admin/block/_pages_list_title.html.twig'), $slug, $author]
  }
}
```

_pages_list_title.html.twig

```
{% set editUrl = ea_url()
                        .setController(ea.crud.controllerFqcn)
                        .setAction('detail')
                        .setEntityId(entity.primaryKeyValue) %}

<a href="{{ editUrl }}" id="Edit_{{ entity.primaryKeyValueAsString }}">    
    {{ '('~entity.primaryKeyValueAsString ~') '~field.formattedValue }}
</a>
// More details
{{ field.label }} // This prints the current field label
{{ entity.fields.getByProperty('author').value.email }}  // Prints author email
```

For **field** refer `EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Dto\FieldDto` class and for **entity** refer `EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Dto\EntityDto` class.

**MORE DETAILS**
This `entity.fields.getByProperty('author')` is again `EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Dto\FieldDto`. Here `'author'` is `AssociationField` so to get its field values just use `entity.fields.getByProperty('author').value.username`